# Azure Active Directory B2C Header issue

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure Active Directory B2C with ASP.NET Core, when I click the sign-in it works like a charm on my local machine but when I deploy my web app in Azure it only works with Edge.

With Chrome and Firefox I always have this error:

I am creating a new web app (social network) and I need to be in beta for November because we go to the show in Toronto related to healthcare.

So to manage all the users (creation, login) I use Azure Active Directory B2C.

When I create the user I use the graph API because I need to do some stuff in my workflow but this part works fine.

After this I created my sign-in policy and I customized my branding.

The first problem I have is the password field, how I can place a placeholder there? (see attached picture).

The second problem I have, when I click the login it works #1 in Edge but in Chrome and Firefox I have this error :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x000D

Someone got this before ?

Comment: 0x000D could be a carriage return somewhere? check the redirect URI. Please post the unattached picture)

Comment: I just ran into this with a new project when trying to login via Microsoft account in Chrome. I'm going to try Edge in a minute to see if it works, but we need the fix as Chrome is most popular.

Comment: Confirmed in Edge it still happens. This is maybe a server side error? I'm going to try debugging it. In the meantime if anyone knows what's up with this please post a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. However, i tried to first "sign up" and then sign in. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to a specific browser and can be reproduced on any oh them with the good repro scenario. I guess your issue is that you try from an HTTP website. Since AADB2C will redirect to an HTTPS page, thus the headers are not well managed and you get this error.

Enforce the https on any website using B2C and you may solve this issue